# Trying to make a quick video game

Tags: python, game-development

The following code is supposed to take an input and loop; internally counting up or down the value of the "player_startPoint" depending on the weather you get from Weather_values  (random number with a range of 2). You win the game by reaching three, However, my code will never leave the while loop.

Coded in Python

```
# import random and set the range of values between 1 & 2 
# remember that zero is the default lowest number when i+1
import pygame 
import random
i = int
weather_values = random.randint(1,2)

# These values are used later to define the game state the user will encounter, if sunny move forward +1; if rainy move backwards -1
# These are most of the variables in general 
Sunny = int = 1
Rainy = int = 2
player_startPoint = 0

# These values will later be replaced once I figure out how to negate case sensitive
yes =  str  
Yes = str
yes == Yes
no = str
No = str
No == no

# This prompt starts the game 
print("This is the weather game")
Ask_string = input("Ask about the weather? (Yes/No): ")

weather_values == Sunny == 1
weather_values == Rainy == 2
if weather_values == Sunny:
    print("Sunny")
    player_startPoint + 1
else :
    weather_values == Rainy
    print("Rainy") 
    player_startPoint - 1

#The value Ask_string prompts the program to run the mathRand command to get a value of 1 or 2 that print out the weather assigned to either number


if Ask_string == "yes" or "Yes":


   #Here we intitute the mathRand function to give the player insight and give them 
   # An input choice to proceed or stay put based on the forcast

   # Printing the variable random abides by the range set and will give you a desired output, 
   # However, I am not sure if random and weather_values will indentify to the same value going forward if just random is used.  
    print (weather_values)

else:
        print("Maybe later then")



# the sunny and rainy variables allow the program associate a value with the object
if weather_values == Sunny :
     player_startPoint =+ 1
else :
    player_startPoint =- 1

#for weather_values in range(1) :
    #player_startPoint + 1
#else :
#    player_startPoint - 1'



while player_startPoint < 3 :
     Ask_string = input("Ask about the weather? (Yes/No): ")

if player_startPoint == 3 :
     print(" Congrats! You've weathered the storm! ")
```

Comment: how can you reach 3 if you do not add anything?

Comment: There is nothing in the `while` loop that changes the value of `player_startPoint`, so why should it ever stop?

Comment: You should definitely read some tutorials about basic scripting/programming constructs. You need to understand what loops are, how variable scopes work and a lot more...

Comment: Thanks guys, this is like my second time coding so yeah I've got a lot to learn. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is simply asking for player input over and over and doing nothing. you should define a function and call that function in the while loop after the user input. there was an error with your syntax where you add or subtract one from `player_startPoint` see code comments.

This will get your loop working as intended but your game is still stuck in an infinite  loop since you add 1 then subtract 1 from `player_startPoint` each loop

This code is not very good there's allot you could do to make it better. research [Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) for a start.

```
# import random and set the range of values between 1 & 2 
# remember that zero is the default lowest number when i+1
import pygame 
import random
i = int
weather_values = random.randint(1,2)

# These values are used later to define the game state the user will encounter, if sunny move forward +1; if rainy move backwards -1
# These are most of the variables in general 
Sunny = int = 1
Rainy = int = 2
player_startPoint = 0

# These values will later be replaced once I figure out how to negate case sensitive
yes =  str  
Yes = str
yes == Yes
no = str
No = str
No == no

# This prompt starts the game 
print("This is the weather game")
# this input is redundent you only ned to call it in the loop
# Ask_string = input("Ask about the weather? (Yes/No): ")


weather_values == Sunny == 1
weather_values == Rainy == 2

#define a function to call when the user inputs an answer
def checkWeather():
    global player_startPoint  #make player_startPoint global so it can be accessed from within the function
    if weather_values == Sunny:
        print("Sunny")
        player_startPoint + 1
    else :
        weather_values == Rainy
        print("Rainy") 
        player_startPoint - 1

    #The value Ask_string prompts the program to run the mathRand command to get a value of 1 or 2 that print out the weather assigned to either number
    if Ask_string == "yes" or "Yes":

    #Here we intitute the mathRand function to give the player insight and give them 
    # An input choice to proceed or stay put based on the forcast

    # Printing the variable random abides by the range set and will give you a desired output, 
    # However, I am not sure if random and weather_values will indentify to the same value going forward if just random is used.  
        print (weather_values)

    else:
            print("Maybe later then")



    # the sunny and rainy variables allow the program associate a value with the object
    if weather_values == Sunny :
        player_startPoint += 1 # =+ is an invalid syntax it should be +=
    else :
        player_startPoint -= 1 # =+ is an invalid syntax it should be +=

    #for weather_values in range(1) :
        #player_startPoint + 1
    #else :
    #    player_startPoint - 1'




while player_startPoint < 3 :
     Ask_string = input("Ask about the weather? (Yes/No): ")
     checkWeather() # call checkWeather function after user input

if player_startPoint == 3 :
     print(" Congrats! You've weathered the storm! ")
```

Comment: Also to negate case sensitive add `.lower()` to the end of the input call `input("Ask about the weather? (Yes/No): ").lower()`